# As a developer, what changes do you make to a vanilla Windows install?

Tags: windows, configuration

When I get a vanilla Windows system, there's a bunch of stuff I change to make it more developer-friendly.

Some of it I remember every time, other stuff I only do as and when.

Examples:

- Show extensions of all file types
- Make hidden and system file visible
- Turn off Windows Defender

I seem to remember a blog post from Jeff on this topic, but can't locate it!

What else do you do, and do you have any tools that automate this process?

Comment: The show extensions thing is my biggest pet peeve about windows, next to inability to scale wallpaper while maintaining aspect ratio. It really creates problems when you have files named MyApp.exe.config, which get shortened to MyApp.exe, While MyApp.exe gets shortend to MyApp. Fun Fun Fun.

Comment: One of the best questions asked on SO.

Answer (score 31):

Indeed I do the above, plus deactivating Zip support (`regsvr32 /u zipfldr.dll`), activating the underscore on Alt shortcuts (Advanced Appearance), replacing Courier New by Andale Mono (replace with your favorite font) in all program settings (after installing it, of course), installing my favorite utilities (UnxUtils, Sysinternals', SciTE, FileMenu Tools which has Command line here and lot of other goodies, etc.) and so on.
Oh, and indeed also deactivate dual keyboard support (French/English), deactivate task grouping, install VirtuaWin (4 desktops), CLCL (clipboard manager), AutoHotkey and my favorite macros, and lot of other freewares, more or less must have.

No automation, alas.

Comment: 1) I don't like it, I prefer to use specialized programs (7-Zip, IZArc) for all my archive needs. Orthogonality...
2) When you search a folder with lot of zips, you feel the pain...
3) I find showing zips as folders just clutter the Explorer tree display. For me, zips are plain files, not folders.

Comment: Thanks for the zip info, windows' just doesn't cut it.

Comment: On newer versions of Windows you can hold down shift while opening a folder's context menu to get the "Open command window here..." option.

Answer (score 21):

I install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to have *nix command line tools and [Xemacs](http://www.xemacs.org/) to have a useful editor.

Comment: I used this for a data structures course recently, and I loved it

Answer (score 17):

I install:

- The usual suspects: Visual Studio, Sql Management Studio, Firefox, Chrome, etc...

  [Paint.Net](http://paint.net/)

  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)

  [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/)

Comment: me too, one of the most useful little apps ever.

Comment: From what I've heard the Mac OS X "equivalent" to Launchy is Quicksilver: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_(software)

Comment: I used to use Launchy. However, with Windows 7 and AutoHotkey, I have remapped Alt+Space to open the Start menu. Then I just type the name of the program I want to open. I'm using an old T42, so every little bit of processor and RAM savings is a win for me.

Answer (score 16):

The first thing I do is open a command prompt and then open the properties for it:

- Switch on Quick Edit. Why is this off by default?
- Increase the window size. Why limit it to the size of a postage stamp?
- Increase the vertical buffer to the maximum possible. Why limit it to a few hundred lines?
- Change the foreground colour to white instead of grey. Why make it less readable than it could be?

In summary: **WHY?**

Comment: Personally, I've switched over to Console2 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) for tabbed console windows

Comment: I hate Quick Edit. If I click in a prompt window and hold the mouse button down slightly too long, it thinks I'm selecting something and the window freezes until I notice what's happening. Drives me crazy.

Comment: Earwicker: it's all for compatibility reasons.  For a detailed reason why quick edit is off by default, see:  http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/13/4886108.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Using the Add\Remove Windows Components in Control Panel, I always remove...

- Games
- Document Templates
- MSN Explorer
- Outlook Express

For the look and feel I...

- Revert to the classic start menu; however, if it's Vista, I leave it as is because I like the indexed search feature.
- Revert to a classic desktop with large icons and make sure that My Computer is the first icon (versus My Documents)
- I also perform the things you mentioned above

Before installing any software I...

- Install any outstanding Windows updates
- Run a Disk Clean Up
- Run Disk Defrag
- Setup scheduled tasks for Clean Up, Defrag, and other personal tools

For tools (outside of my IDEs and other necessary development tools), I install..

- TweakUI
- IE6, IE7, Safari, Chrome, Opera, and Firefox
- Install the set of Firefox plug-ins I always use for development
- 'Open Command Prompt Here' shell extension
- Install Consolas and set it as the default font for my editors (IDEs, Notepad++, etc)

Comment: If you remove games, how do you play minesweeper when you're compiling?

Comment: Compile Time is synonymous for one of two things: (1) catch up on my RSS reader, (2) browse SO =)

Comment: Im glad SOMEONE made a minesweeper joke :D

Comment: FYI the vista start menu search is available in the classic menu, but I still leave aero enabled since I like the screen shots when I alt+tab.

Answer (score 12):

I wipe it and install Linux.  Everyone is always amazed by how productive I can be.  It's because I don't spend half my time fighting with the machine.

Comment: fighting with the machine means, that you didn't find all the features of the OS you need. Do you really think Windows doesn't everything Linux has usability wise?

Comment: Seeing this reply after 10 years while drinking my tears because the systems of my client do not support any other OS than windows. *cries in a corner*

Answer (score 11):

- Install Consolas font and turn on (and tune) ClearType.
- Install [ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) to magnify display during presentations.
- Install FireFox/Firebug
- Install [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com) Win Explorer alternative (can't live without it!)
- Install [DeskPins](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/deskpins.html) to be able to make any Window temporarily topmost.
- Make sure OneNote got installed with Office.
- Install Visio.
- Install favorite editor (whatever it is at the time, currently SCiTE).
- Install 7Zip.
- Fix Windows colors to suit me and put picture of RatPack (Dean's my hero) as wallpaper.

Answer (score 10):

Disable shortcuts to FilterKeys, StickyKeys, and ToggleKeys - nothing frustrates me more than having to deal with that cruddy feature because I push the shift key down several times while I'm thinking or hold it down for eight seconds (again, while thinking) before I start typing!

Change the default action for Folder to explore instead of open.

Comment: Never understood why the *Keys are ON by default...  I guess most normal users know what they're about to type.

Comment: They're probably on by default because if you *need* them to be on, it's difficult to turn them on.

Answer (score 8):

over the years i have arrived to the decision that i do as little customization as possible since workplaces change and computers change (both at home and at work).

i used to do all kinds of crazy tweaks with litestep, setting up partitions, etc. these days i pare it down to the basics, and it does not take me long to setup a machine and have a familiar environment.

in addition to the usual "win32dev" setup (classic scheme, optimized for performance, no special effects, show all files, details in explorer views, blue background, etc) i have the following stack:

- cygwin (gcc, vim, curl, wget, perl/ruby/python, svn, git, ssh, netcat, etc; rxvt for terminal)
- ffox + adblock + dev plugins
- clipx for simple stack-like clipboard with previews
- textpad + a few basics syntax highlighters
- virtuawin - the only minimal window manager that does all i need and nothing more
- autoHotKey for basic app shortcuts
- procexp to replace task manager
- all other sysinternals tools
- tortoise svn
- putty + agent + keys
- 7zip
- keepass
- wireshark

everything i install by hand goes into c:\programs (for easy no-space, lowercase paths).

Answer (score 7):

#### Command line scripts

For storing scripts that I use from the command line I create a `Command Line Scripts` directory under Program Files and add it to the PATH environment variable. I use the following batch file for listing and editing those scripts:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set UTILPATH=C:\Program Files\System Tools\Command Line Utilities

if not "x%1"=="x" (

start "" "notepad" "%UTILPATH%\%1.bat"

) else (

dir /b "%UTILPATH%" | grep -v com.bat | grep -P "(exe|bat|cmd)" | sed "s/\.\(exe\|bat\|cmd\)//"
echo.

)
```

(note that the filtering of the directory listing depends on some unix commands I have installed via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/))

I give it the name com.bat, (short for command) then I can:

- list the scripts in that directory by typing `com` at the command prompt
- edit any script in the list by typing `com script-name` at the command prompt*, similarly:
- create new scripts in that directory by typeing `com new-script-name` at the command prompt*
- and if I ever need to edit com.bat I just type `com com`

* As I'm running Vista I have to use an elevated command prompt as directories under `Program Files` are protected.
For a quick way to launch an elevated command prompt, simply press the `Win key`; type `cmd`; press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`; and then hit `Alt+C` to confirm the elevation prompt. Six keystrokes to an elevated command prompt! ([via][4])

#### Startup Script

One of the scripts I store in my `Command Line Scripts` directory is a script that is run when I log in to windows (via the `Task Scheduler`, type `Task` in the Vista start menu). I use that script to set up several **virtual drives** using the [subst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst) command to directories I access frequently or want a quick way to access on the command prompt or for **shortening path names** in compiler warnings, logs or debug output.

My Startup script looks something like this:

```
@setlocal
@set _MYDOCS_=%USERPROFILE%\Documents

@REM Note: first delete the drives so I can run script again
@REM       to fix drives that failed to get mapped

subst /d W:
subst /d T:
subst /d S:
subst /d R:
subst /d N:
subst /d L:
subst /d H:
subst W: "%_MYDOCS_%\Work\SVN Working Copy\Website\trunk\www"
subst T: "%_MYDOCS_%\Work\SVN Working Copy\project 1\trunk"
subst S: "%_MYDOCS_%\Work\SVN Working Copy"
subst R: "%_MYDOCS_%\Work\SVN Working Copy\project 2\branches\12.50"
subst N: "%_MYDOCS_%\Work\SVN Working Copy\project 2\trunk"
subst L: "%_MYDOCS_%\Work\"
subst H: "%_MYDOCS_%\My Projects\Haslers.info\Working Copy"
```

Note that subst can be a little temperamental and occasionally the drives don't get created and I have to run the startup script again manually.

Comment: subst is a nice, nice little command, when everything goes okay. :)

Answer (score 7):

Regarding:

> - Show extensions of all file types
> - Make hidden and system file visible

I don't like making hidden files visible all the time (it makes two desktop.ini visible on my windows Vista desktop for starters) so I use an explorer extension to make it easy to toggle this on and off. There's also a corresponding one for file extensions:

- [HiddenFilesToggle Context-Menu Shell Extension](http://students.kennesaw.edu/~rzillige/shell/HiddenFilesToggle.html)
- [FileExtensionToggle Context-Menu Shell Extension](http://students.kennesaw.edu/~rzillige/shell/FileExtensionToggle.html)

Comment: Yeah, the two desktop.ini thing is a pain - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/). I find that I can't develop without this clipboard history tool.

Answer (score 6):

#### Step 1: Fix windows

- Turn off System Restore
- Turn off Windows Defender
- Uninstall any OEM-supplied antivirus or other crapware if it's an OEM box
- Get [SysInternals AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and **lay the smackdown** to all the 8000 useless startup items and services vista inflicts upon you, including the slow and useless vista search indexing service.

#### Step 2: Install stuff.

Now that my shiny new Core 2 Duo PC isn't bogged down with useless crap running like a 386, I can build it up again

- Install Firefox
- Install FlashPlayer firefox plugin (*why oh why isn't this bundled with FF?*)
- Run windows update and let it do it's download/reboot cycle 50 times until it's happy

  - While this is happening I can use firefox to browse stackoverflow and read reddit :-)
- Get [UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and either unzip them to system32, or otherwise make sure they are in the path.

  - This is neccessary because I can't stand cygwin, yet my muscle memory keeps typing `ls` when I try to type `dir`, and windows still hasn't heard of `grep` yet
- Install Droid Sans Mono and Monaco fonts for programming
- Install E-TextEditor
- If I'm installing visual studio, do that. If not install the .NET framework runtime instead
- Install Firefox addons (firebug, fission, web developer, adblock)

Answer (score 4):

I add Wordpad to the Send To context menu.  [Instructions for XP here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310270).  Works in Vista, as well.

Comment: Often times, I'm not allowed to install additional software on a machine, and Wordpad is preferable to Notepad.

Answer (score 4):

Someone gave me a 'Delete all SVN folders' registry script - that is a must have for me, now (it's somewhere on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224430/xcopy-aspnet-deployment-of-a-subversion-managed-project) thread).

I leave UAC on - last thing I want is to write code that works with UAC off, but fails miserably with it on. Before I started to use Virtual PC to set up test environments for my code, I tried to leave my desktop as 'vanilla' as possible - I wanted to test under conditions reasonably similar to an everyday non-developer user.

All of the above is for my home development system. I try to do the same at work, within reason. Except for the SVN stuff, because we use TFS at my office.

Answer (score 4):

I always install the following to make it easier to manage and interact with windows

- [Taskix](http://taskix.robustit.com/) - Reorder buttons in your Windows taskbar
- [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) - scroll the window directly beneath the mouse cursor
- [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) - organize your windows by tiling, resizing and positioning them
- [allSnap](http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/) - windows automatically snap to window edges and (optionally) the edges of other windows

Comment: Thanks for the tip on WinSplit Revolution... Very handy for using my new wide-screen monitor more effectively.

Answer (score 4):

I like to:

- Make the taskbar larger so that it can hold two rows of applications
- Disable personalized menus in the start menu
- Disable grouping of similar taskbar items

I also randomly open a lot of PuTTY sessions to various machines, so I like to create a "bin" directory in my home folder, add it to the PATH, and then create a shortcut to PuTTY in it named "p" (among other shortcuts). I can then easily Windows-R (run) and type `p [putty-session-name]` to open the session. This has saved me tons of time / mouse clicks.

Answer (score 4):

I follow the [extensive recipe for making a Windows system useful](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/win32-cheat.html) built and maintained by Simon Peyton Jones.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great list, even if a little quaint in places. (reading mac floppies! when did you last see one of those?)

Answer (score 3):

Turn off Autorun so that I'm not accidentally installing malware or crapware.

Here's a couple of links, out of many:

http://antivirus.about.com/od/securitytips/ht/autorun.htm
http://news.cnet.com/8301-13554_3-9894970-33.html?tag=mncol;txt

Comment: A good tip. Installing VMware does take care of it though, so I don't usually do it manually myself.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things no-one else mentioned

- Install [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) for tabbed cmd windows
- Install Powershell
- Completely replace Notepad with [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)

Answer (score 2):

I install some set of *nix command utilities and process explorer at a bare minimum.

Also, on XP systems I disable any theming and use the windows classic coloration. Vista just doesn't look or work right without the Aero theme so I can't do that on Vista without going almost completely nuts.

Also forgot, I install Chrome. (Used to be Firefox but Chrome is nicer out of the box)

Comment: What's great with Process Explorer is that you can replace the regular Task Manager with it. (Options > Replace Task Manager)

Comment: I always do that. Task Manager is useless in comparison.

Answer (score 2):

- Install the full IIS.
- Set the resolution high enough.
- Set the background to Grey.
- Show hidden and system files.
- Toolbar 2 or 3 high (I run one monitor sideways).
- Always show file extentions.

Answer (score 2):

I use [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) to prepare the windows installation disk in order to have some typical settings already set right after the installation.

For example:

- Explorer-Associate additional file types with Notepad
- Explorer-Classic Control Panel
- Explorer-Disable Beep on errors
- Explorer-Disable Prefix: Shortcut to
- Explorer-Show extensions of known file-types
- Explorer-Show hidden files and folders
- Explorer-Show the full path in the Title Bar
- Performance-Disable Info Tips on Files and Folders
- Performance-Disable Last accessed Timestamp on files
- Taskbar-Disable Group similar Taskbar buttons
- Taskbar-Disable Language-Bar
- Taskbar-Lock the Taskbar-Yes

You can also remove useless parts of the system:

- Accessibility Options
- Briefcase
- ClipBook Viewer

Answer (score 1):

I install all of the shell extensions I normally use (TortoiseSVN and CommandHere for example).

Also, one of the first things I do after I reimage a machine is make sure it's hooked to all of my network shares properly. Few things derail my work as quickly as having to fight with the network to get a file at an inopportune time.

Answer (score 1):

Install emacs + a selection of gnuwin32 packages.

Also proexp to replace task manager.

Answer (score 1):

Edi Weitz has a nice writeup of his customizations: [Making Windows usable for old Linux farts](http://www.weitz.de/win/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch to classic menu
2. Increase the taskbar hight to have more shortcuts & lock the taskbar
3. Performance options -> Adjust for best performance
4. Copy all the backed up shortcuts files to Favorites folder
5. Install necessary software (JDK, DBMS stuff, Editplus, MS Office etc.)
6. Driver for soundcard
7. New network connection for Broadband ...

Answer (score 0):

I generally leave Windows Defender online but I don't use an antivirus so....

I set my start menu to display small icons and to have no "most recently used programs" active.  Instead I pin everything to my start menu:

[My start menu http://www.robpaveza.net/pub/startmenu.png](http://www.robpaveza.net/pub/startmenu.png)

I also make sure that all the extension menus are actual menus, not just links, and that my computer and user files icons are shown on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I download and install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is a really good thread... I'm going to have to go through all the suggestions and see what I'm mission out on :)

Off the bat, I install:

- Google Chrome
- Visual Studio 2008
- aShampoo CD Burning suite (or whatever my current favorite burning suite is)
- IZArc (or whatever my current favorite is)
- RocketDock - I use it to replace Quick Launch.
- Songbird

When I used XP (I'm on Vista now) I'd always install Tweak UI and tweak everything to my liking.  Like listing My Computer before My Documents.
I remove the Help icon from the start menu.
I make it so Network Neighborhood was displayed in the start menu.
I have it show file extensions and show hidden files/folders.

Comment: Is that supposed to mean "missing out"?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I do is making sure everything is updated and all superfluous junk in the background turned off. I hadn't done a fresh install of Windows for years until very recently, so I forgot how painful this step was (4-5 hours...)

One of the first things I do is download the ClearType Tuner from the [PowerToys page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx). I find the OS's default settings give the text very visible colour fringes no matter which LCD I use it on, and it ends up causing eyestrain after a while. Sometimes I'll just turn it off entirely.

After that I install the usual stuff; Firefox, gVim, Command Prompt powertoy, 7-Zip, ...

Answer (score 0):

Install dev tools (take your pick). Source Control, DB, IDE, Unit testing tools, etc.

Assumption: I have full rights over the box.

Install latest drivers, Windows updates, Firefox, [Evernote](http://evernote.com), [Live Mesh](http://mesh.com), [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org), [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/?utm_campaign=new_w&utm_content=new&utm_medium=new&utm_source=new) (for IM & social networks), [Zune](http://www.zune.net/en-US/default.htm) (for music & podcasts)

Answer (score 0):

- vim (the windows port is quite good)
- mssoffice
- cygwin (The cygwin setup is a pain in the ass, however I found it the easiest way to get gcc running)
- visual studio
- FF or Chrome
- Adobe Reader :D
- There is also [1] a driver for ext2/3 if you have a Linux installation, or just ext2/3 formated disks or flash drives.

I guess that's not all, just everything which came in my mind.

[1] http://www.fs-driver.org/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to cygwin I use [ch](http://www.softintegration.com/) it's a free unixshell + utils and is a 'c' interpreter.
Their website is a bit nephew-art but the product is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how many of you use nLite/vLite to create a custom installer for Windows???

My development tools get installed:

- [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)
- Firefox plugins (WebDeveloper, FireBug, etc)

Plus many more...

Answer (score 0):

Mainly : Visual Studio , SQL Server  and some extensions for them such as Rock Scroll etc.

Being a web developer I install 4 other browsers (along IE) : Opera, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Also :

- SysInternals Process Explorer Altova
- Altova XML Spy
- Winamp
- Office 2007
- Altova Diff Dog
- Paint.NET
- Yahoo Messenger
- Skype
- Reflector
- ViewState Decoder
- Oracle SQL Developer
- FastStone Image Viewer
- TextPad
- DC++
- FeedReader
- .NET Memory Profiler (SciTech)
- HttpLook
- NetBeans
- SQLDigger
- Winamp
- Workrave
- Manic Time
- MySQL  (including alpha such as 6.0)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install latest service pack.
   Usually, I slipstream it anyway.
2. Prevent applications from stealing
   focus.
   http://xphelpandsupport.mvps.org/how_do_i_prevent_applications_fr.htm
3. Copy my command line apps ([basic unix commands](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)) and [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) apps.
4. Windows Updates
5. Install developer tools like Visual Studio, Eclipse, VirtualBox, etc.

I'm leaning more towards having service based applications like SQL Server be installed on a base lined Virtual Machine and run from there. That way I only have it running when I need to and I can extend the performance life of my Windows install.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install wipfw (and a decent ruleset) **before** hooking the box to the Internet.
2. Install Far Manager + some plugins.
3. Install vim.
4. Install gkrellm.

All this used to happen in the past. Nowadays I'm using Linux exclusively and I'm happy with it. I'm not a fanboy, neither I'm a zealot. Linux just does the job for me so I stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Image Resizer](http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/), a clone of one of the Windows XP Powertoys; suiting Windows 7 64bit. Very handy for making thumbnail images via the context menu in Windows Explorer.