# How can I change the repository url using AnkhSVN 2.x

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I'm connecting to my Subersion server (VisualSVN server 1.6.3) using Ankh v2.0.5250.202 on VS 2008

The current url for my repository is https://svnserver:8443/svn/foo/foo/trunk/ and I want to switch to https://svnserver:6002/svn/foo/foo/trunk/

I'm using the "Switch To" tool to select a new URL 'available on the right hand of the url bar in the "pending changes" window.

Unfortunately, when I select the new url, I get an error stating that 
**'https://svnserver:8443/svn/foo/foo/trunk'
is not the same repository as
'https://svnserver:6002/svn/foo'**

I've tried to input 'https://svnserver:6002/svn/foo', 'https://svnserver:6002/svn/foo/foo', 'https://svnserver:6002/svn/foo/foo/trunk', but I'm always getting the same error.

Is there a fix? Or a config file that I can manually edit ? (I didn't find such a config file)

Note : On the server side, I've juste changed the server port without touching anything else. I can browse through the repository using the repository explorer so I think the problem is on the client side.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the daily builds of AnkhSVN (and since March 2009 the stable version) the Switch command will handle this case for you.

AnkhSVN will detect that the repository root doesn't match and then it will ask you if you wish to relocate.

See http://ankhsvn.net/daily/ for the daily builds.

Answer (score 6):

The "switch" command is the wrong command to use!

You have to use the "relocate" command. Not sure if AnkhSVN has this though.

For the svn client, you have to use

```
svn switch --relocate FROM TO [PATH...]
```

(yes, it's the 'switch' command, but only UI wise - internally, relocating uses a completely different API than switch).

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of troubles while I was working with AnkhSVN and subversion.

I have a very easy idea to switch solution to another repository. It seems strange but it really works.

At firs you have to export a template from your current project. Now create new solution using your own template, then add new solution to new subversion directory and delete your template from MyDocuments. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Ughhhh, it's a pain. I had a similar issue for a long time, and I'm still a bit shakey on how to get it to work. My answer may not be applicable (I hope it helps though).

Try clearing the SVN folders that are hidden in your project's directory... take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224430/xcopy-asp-net-deployment-of-a-subversion-managed-project). The very last answer has a good method for clearing the hidden SVN folders if you don't know how (warning, it requires a registry tweak).

Once you do that, you should be able to change repositories. Unfortunately, I could not find any config files to manually edit.