# SVN Versus TFS for asp.net web application

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tfs

I am searching for a tool which provides the following features for developing ASP.NET web application using Visual Studio 2012:

1. Version-control,
2. Bug-tracking,
3. Source-control,
4. Multiple users working and accessing the same project at the same time,
5. Integration with Visual Studio 2012.

All of the above features come with TFS, but in my case we have a small development team (less than 5) and I was thinking that free tools such as SVN might be more cost effective comparing to TFS which might be more suitable for large teams.

**Q1)** So can anyone advice if Apache Subversion SVN will be able to achieve the above 5 main features?

**Q2)** Second question, if I go with SVN rather than TFS what are the features I am going to miss or can not achieve in SVN?

Comment: What's the difference between version-control and source-control? ;)

Comment: If you have an MSDN subscription, TFS is free for teams of 5 or less.

Comment: in version control we will have versions with dates , major changes in each version , etc. While source control we will be able to secure the source code and manage the source code by multiple -users.

Comment: @JamesReed but will the free TFS covers the integration with Sharepoint 2013.As i will need this feature in the future as we will be working on a sharePoint web application for our compnay.

Comment: It looks like The sharepoint integration [doesn't come with tfs explress](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express.aspx). The Sharepoint integration is used for Project Planning (sprint planning etc). If you're developing a sharepoint site for your company then the TFS Sharepoint integration has absolutly nothing to do with this. Unless of course your sharepoint web application it going to interact with TFS in some way (display work items etc)

Answer (score 4):

Apache Subversion can be your best friend but I want to quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/661466/761095):

> One can not compare between TFS and SVN!

**Points 1 and 3:** definitely yes.

**Point 2:** you can integrate SVN with a bug-tracker, even with client-side bells and whistles. E.g. check TortoiseSVN client Manual: ["Integration with Bug Tracking Systems / Issue Trackers".](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html)

**Point 4:** definitely yes.

**Point 5:** yes. Check [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) extension for Visual Studio. You can use it for free if your machines are not in a domain.

As for Apache Subversion server you may want to look at [VisualSVN Server Standard Edition](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) which is also free. It would be the best choice for Windows environment, in fact.

Comment: Other options for a server are CollabNet SvnEdge and WanDisco's Ubersvn. For Visual Studio integration you can also check out AnkhSVN. The differences between these products aren't that large so it mostly depends on personal preference whichever you like most.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can achieve the point 1,3,4,5. With Point 2 i'm not sure.

But you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661389/tfs-vs-svn)