# SVN - Change address

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I have a Subversion server running at a location. On the internal network, I connect to it via a `192.168.1.x` internal IP.

The repository server is accessible the the internet as well.

I am now outside of the LAN. I know the IP Address of the server, and can browse to it using a web browser. I am using VS2012. I am unsure what to change to make my VS2012 session connect to the external IP, and use the same code.

I need to it change to my `202.134.121.x` style address.

What should be change? I am using `ankhsvn` to integrate VS2012 with my SVN repository.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458791/how-can-i-change-the-repository-url-using-ankhsvn-2-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should run `svn switch --relocate` on your local SVN working copy to change its remote URL to use the external IP. According to the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html), this would look something like:

```
$ svn switch --relocate svn+ssh://192.168.1.x/svn/repo svn+ssh://202.134.121.x/svn/repo
```

See the [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) for more details.